# OpsCenter unable to connect to existing cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I have a cassandra cluster on two nodes. On a 3rd node, I install OpsCenter and I try to connect to the existing cassandra cluster, the problem is that when I try to connect from OpsCenter it throws the next:

node1: 172.16.8.232

node2: 172.16.8.233

node3(not in the cassandra cluster): 172.16.8.231

```
Error creating cluster: Unable to connect to cluster. Error is: Unable to connect to any seed nodes, tried [u'172.16.8.232', u'172.16.8.233']
```

I have try to connect using cqls from the node3 to the cluster:

```
cqlsh 172.16.8.232 9042
```

And it works fine, I connect successfully, so I think the problem will be in OpsCenter, maybe is a incompatible versio?

Cassandra version: 3.0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpsCenter 5.2.x only supports up to Cassandra 2.1.  OpsCenter 6.0 only supports DataStax Enterprise.  So there is no way to use OpsCenter with Apache Cassandra 2.2+.  More info in our [compatibility table](http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/compatibility.html#compatibilityDocument__opsc-compatibility) and not on [OpsCenter policy changes](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/opsc/opscPolicyChanges.html).

Comment: Yes Really thanks, I had check it yesterday :P, Any alternatibe of OpsCenter for cassandra? thanks